# C: I keep getting errors that say error: expected expression

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, function-calls

I keep getting five errors in my code that say error: expected expression when talking about the variables in my function. I have looked on this site and other places but I can't find what's wrong.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void separate_digits (long int n);
void print_array ( int a[10] );
int digits_different ( int a[10] );
int divisible ( int a[10], int n );

int main ()
{
    long int n;

printf("Enter a positive integer or 0 (zero) to end:");
scanf("%ld\n", &n);

while ( n != 0)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong input\n");
    }

    else
    {
        separate_digits (long int n);
    }

    printf("Enter a positive integer or 0 (zero) to end:");
    scanf("%ld\n", &n);
}

printf("*** Program Terminated ***\n");

}

void separate_digits (long int n)
{
    int a[10] = {0};
    int digit;
    int num = n;

while ( num > 0)
{
    digit = num % 10;

    ++a[digit];

    num = num / 10;
}

print_array ( int a[10] );

if ( a[0] != 0 )
{
    printf("Wrong input for the second part.\n");
    printf("Input should not contain zero.\n");
}

else if ( digits_different ( int a[10] ) == FALSE )
{
    printf("Wrong input for the second part.\n");
    printf("Input should not contain each digit more than once.\n");
}

else if ( divisible ( int a[10], int n ) == FALSE )
{
    printf("%1ld is not divisible by its digits.\n", n);
}

else
{
    printf("%1ld is divisible by its digits.\n", n);
   }
}

void print_array ( int a[10] )
{
int i;

printf("\n\n\n");
printf("Digits:         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9\n");
printf("Occurrences:    ");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("a[i]   ");
}
}

 int digits_different ( int a[10] )
{
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > 1)
        return FALSE;

    else
        return TRUE;
}
}

int divisible ( int a[10], int n )
{
int i;
int num;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 0)
        continue;
    else if (num % i != 0)
        return FALSE;
}

return TRUE;
}
```

Here's the errors I keep getting:

```
Lab_Assignment_6_Sarah_H.c:27:21: error: expected expression
         separate_digits (long int n);
                                     ^
Lab_Assignment_6_Sarah_H.c:53:16: error: expected expression
         print_array ( int a[10] );
                  ^
Lab_Assignment_6_Sarah_H.c:61:31: error: expected expression
        else if ( digits_different ( int a[10] ) == FALSE )
                                 ^
Lab_Assignment_6_Sarah_H.c:67:24: error: expected expression
        else if ( divisible ( int a[10], int n ) == FALSE )
                          ^
Lab_Assignment_6_Sarah_H.c:67:35: error: expected expression
        else if ( divisible ( int a[10], int n ) == FALSE )
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the type of the parameter, `separate_digits (long int n);` --> `separate_digits (n);`

Comment: your `main` function is missing a return statement, and `int main()` is bad form, use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be prepending your variables with a type name when you actually pass them to a function.

That's only required in the *declarations* for those functions, as you've done near the top of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The function call syntax only takes the variable name, not the type.

```
separate_digits (long int n);
```

should be

```
separate_digits (n);
```

Also, `print_array ( int a[10] );` is wrong, you only need to pass the array name to pass the array, like

```
  print_array ( a );
```

and so on.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.1, *Postfix operators*, function call syntax

> *postfix-expression ( argument-expression-list<sub>opt</sub> )*

and

> *argument-expression-list:*
>   *assignment-expression*
>   *argument-expression-list , assignment-expression*

there, the *"type"* is not to be mentioned in argument list, it is

> An argument may be an expression of any complete object type.

In other words, each element in the *argument-expression-list* need to have a type which is not to be *written*.

Answer (score 0):

`separate_digits (long int n);` is not syntactically correct. This is confusing the compiler.

Drop the `long int` to give `separate_digits (n);`